# Confused about the generation of mipmap in metal?

Tags: metal

I set `mipmapped` to `YES` in `texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat` and call `generateMipmapsForTexture` method of `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` on given texture to automatically generate mipmaps.

The question is if I have set the `mipmapped` to `YES`, doesn't it means that the resulting image should be mipmapped, why should I need `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to explicit generate mipmaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, so let's walk through it.

`texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat` takes `format`, `width`, `height` and `mipmapped` as parameters. The `mipmapped` parameter is there to tell Metal to calculate the number of mip levels that resulting image will have, since there is no parameter to pass mip level count. Here's how it's described in documentation:

> `mipmapped`
>
> A `Boolean` indicating whether the resulting image should be
>   mipmapped. If `YES`, then the `mipmapLevelCount` property in the returned
>   descriptor is computed from `width` and `height`. If `NO`, then
>   `mipmapLevelCount` is `1`.

If you would use `newTextureWithDescriptor` with texture descriptor you created explicitly, then there's no `mipmapped` parameter, since you explicitly pass number of mip levels in `mipmapLevelCount` property of `MTLTextureDescriptor`.

Since you create a new texture, there's no reason to **generate** mipmaps, since the texture is empty.

The `generateMipmapsForTexture` method is used to generate mipmaps for a texture that *already* has mip levels and you just need to populate them with mipmaps generated automatically.

So, to get this straight, `mipmapped` parameter just tells Metal to create a texture that has mip levels, that you can later populate (if you want) with `generateMipmapsForTexture` (or in some other ways, such as using texture as color attachment in render pass with level specified).

Comment: What if set `mipmapped` to `NO` when creating texture, however in the later process found out that I need to generate mipmaps for that texture, what should I do then？

Comment: Create a new texture with `mipmapped` set to `YES`, copy the first mip layer of original texture to the new texture's first layer generate mipmap using blit encoder.

Comment: But, I think, since mipmapped texture should only take ~1.5 the space the texture withtout mipmaps takes, you should probably just create the textures that are likely to need mipmaps with `mipmapped` set to `YES`, if you aren't memory constrained.

Comment: If you are still confused, I can edit the answer, just try to describe the confusing part.

Comment: Always set `mipmapped` to `YES' seems a good way to avoid additional blit operation when need to generate mipmaps, does it will cause a performance issue?

Comment: Well, you shouldn't just add mipmaps to all the textures blindly, since that will increase memory usage. Can you describe your use case for the texture that is created without mipmaps, but then needs them?

Comment: Got it. Currently no such scene yet. Thank you for your reply, your answer had solved the confusion in my mind.

Comment: If you liked my answer, please consider accepting it as an answer, @coulsonwang.